# determine unique many-to-many relationships sql

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I feel like this is a relatively simple problem, but I'm having trouble articulating the issue to find an answer. I was given data in a format that's nothing like what I need, so I'm trying to preprocess it using SQL. I'd also take a response using R as a solution.

Right now what I have is:

```
pID     GroupID
A        1
A        2
A        3
B        2
B        4
C        2 
D        1
D        4
```

And what I need is this:

```
GroupID      pID
1            A,D
2            A,B,C
3            A
4            B,D
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'r using mysql you can use group by and group_concat.

E.g something like:
SELECT GroupID, group_concat(pID) FROM table_name GROUP BY GroupID

This works in PostgreSQL:
select groupid,array_to_string(array_agg(pid),',') from t group by groupid;

Comment: I just tried 
SELECT GroupID, group_concat(pID) FROM table_name GROUP BY GroupID
and am still just not in the format I need. I'd like to combine the pIDs. Is this possible?

Comment: @Daina: please post the output you get (as an update to your post)

Comment: Wow sorry for the delay. I'm new here and thought I posted that I fixed it back on the 20th but must not have actually added the comment. @Gerd's solution works fine, I just needed to add a WHERE as the data I'm working with is more complicated than my example. Sorry again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 10 or late, you can use the listagg function:

```
 WITH aset
         AS (SELECT 'a' pid, 1 GROUP_ID
               FROM DUAL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'a' pid, 2 GROUP_ID
               FROM DUAL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'b' pid, 2 GROUP_ID
               FROM DUAL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'b' pid, 3 GROUP_ID
               FROM DUAL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'c' pid, 2 GROUP_ID
               FROM DUAL)
      SELECT group_id,  LISTAGG (pid, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pid) AS pid
        FROM aset
    GROUP BY group_id
```

This returns

```
GROUP_ID PID
1        a
2        a,b,c
3        b
```